# Why extracting React Context provider logic to a custom provider avoids unnecessary rerenders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

The problem with the following snippet is that components `A` and `B` will be rerendered whenever the change button is clicked, whereas I would like only component `C` to be rerendered as it is the only one consuming context:

```
const UserContext = React.createContext({user: {name: 'name1'}, change: () => null})
const useUserContext = () => React.useContext(UserContext)

const A = () => {
    console.log('rendering A')
    return <B/>
}
const B = () => {
    console.log('rendering B')
    return <C/>
}

const C = () => {
    const user = useUserContext()
    console.log('rendering C', user)

    return (
        <div>
            <div>UserName:{user.user.name}</div>
            <button onClick={user.change}>Change</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState({name: 'name2'})

    const change = () => {
        console.log('changing name')
        setUser({name: 'name3'})
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <UserContext.Provider value={{user, change}}>
                <A/>
            </UserContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I mitigated the issue completely by extracting the provider logic to a custom provider:

```
const UserContext = React.createContext({user: {name: 'name1'}, change: () => null})
const useUserContext = () => React.useContext(UserContext)

const UserProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState({name: 'name2'})

    const change = () => {
        console.log('changing name')
        setUser({name: 'name3'})
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{user, change}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

const A = () => {
    console.log('rendering A')
    return <B/>
}
const B = () => {
    console.log('rendering B')
    return <C/>
}

const C = () => {
    const user = useUserContext()
    console.log('rendering C', user)

    return (
        <div>
            <div>UserName:{user.user.name}</div>
            <button onClick={user.change}>Change</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <UserProvider>
                <A/>
            </UserProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, I don't understand why this should make any difference to React? Can someone explain what happens behind the scenes in both cases?

Comment: Here's a [good reference](https://componentbasedcarlos.com/blog/using-children-props-to-prevent-rerenders-in-react-js/) that says basically the same thing as Oktay's answer. Basically any component that is rendered in a component where state has changed you can expect to get re-rendered. But it's also very important to **not care about rerenders until and unless you experience perfomance issues**. React is designed to be fast (enough) in 98% of cases without having to care about the number of re-renders. If you experience logic problems caused by re-renders, then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSX` compiles into `React.createElement(...)` and it returns an object. Diffing algorithm compares that object on each render. If `UserProvider` accepts `children` prop as component instance (an object from `createElement`), that object does not change its reference even if `UserProvider` rerenders, since it is not created inside `UserProvider`, but in its parent.

- **Render** happens when the component type is different than the previous
  render.
- **Re-render** happens when the component instance is different
  than the previous render.

In your first example `React.createElement(A)` gets called on each render. In your second example - only once in `App`

If you transform your first example like this:

```
 const children = <A />  // createElement is called only once, outside of the component
 const App = () => {
     const [user, setUser] = React.useState({name: 'name2'})
 
     const change = () => {
         console.log('changing name')
         setUser({name: 'name3'})
     }
    
     return (
         <div>
             <UserContext.Provider value={{user, change}}>
                 {children}
             </UserContext.Provider>
         </div>
     )
 }
```

It will not rerender